# Can you define an upper sum as a function?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

I am a student studying real-analysis, and I had this thought today about an alternative solution I could have used for a problem I saw in the past; However I am not sure it doesn't rely on invalid mathematical assumptions, as I've haven't seen sums in the context of functions before. Is it possible to define a Riemann sum as a function? For example, let's say that for a given function $f$ I am told that:

$$\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}\left[\overline{S}(f,P_{n})-\underline{S}(f,P_{n})\right]=0$$

Then, can I define a function $g(x)=\overline{S}(f,P_{x})-\underline{S}(f,P_{x}) \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$ and conclude that $\underset{x\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}g(x)=0$?

(Just to be safe and make sure my notation is understood: $P_n$ is a partition, and $\overline{S}(f,P_{x}),\underline{S}(f,P_{x})$  refer to Upper and Lower sums respectively, that is, in the context of determining whether a function is integrable)

Comment: What does $g(1.5) = \overline{S}(f, P_{1.5}) - \underline{S}(f, P_{1.5})$ mean for, say, $f(x) = x^2$?

Comment: Oh, because summation and partitions relies on a (natural) index, it's not properly defined? I understand now, thank you!

Comment: You seem to be asking whether you can extend a sequence to the real numbers.  If so, the answer is yes, but I know of no natural way to extend this sequence.  You can artificially do so by writing $$g(x) = (1-\{x\})g(\lfloor{x}\rfloor) + \{x\}g(\lceil{x}\rceil)$$
where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the greatest integer $\leq x$, $\lceil x\rceil$ is the smallest integer $\geq x$, and $\{x\} = x - \lfloor x\rfloor$ is the fractional part of $x$.

Comment: What does {x} refer to? Not sure I understood the meaning of the curly braces in this context

Comment: @AriB I edited in all the definitions I was using in my previous comment.  The idea is just to define $g(n)$ with the given sequence and then "connect the dots" with a line in between any two consecutive natural numbers.  Again, this is a fairly artificial method, but sometimes it suffices to extend a sequence to the reals (and yes, it maintains the same limiting properties at $x \to \infty$)

Comment: Another comment: your "function" $g$ is already defined on $\mathbb N$ as a "function". Why do you want to extend it on $\mathbb R$?